# When opening a new page it overlapses the NavigationView menu

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I made a basic app that has a menu with two options, each of them takes to a new page. The problem is that those pages are launched over the main one so it overlapses the menu and everything behind. Those pages don't have any content, their code is an simple xaml and xaml.cs.

I used some examples that Microsoft developer webpage gives, but the result is the same. I haven't found any other possible solution and I am not able to understand what is happening.

Page that contains the menu

```
<Grid>
  <NavigationView
    x:Name="NavView"
    ItemInvoked="NavViewItemInvoked"
    Windows10version1803:BackRequested="NavViewBackRequested"
    Windows10version1803:IsBackEnabled="{x:Bind Frame.CanGoBack, Mode=OneWay}"
  >
    <NavigationView.MenuItems>
      <NavigationViewItem x:Name="HomePage" Content="Home" Icon="Home" />
      <NavigationViewItem x:Name="AddPage" Content="Add" Icon="Add" />
    </NavigationView.MenuItems>

    <NavigationView.AutoSuggestBox>
      <AutoSuggestBox x:Name="SearchBox" QueryIcon="Find" />
    </NavigationView.AutoSuggestBox>

    <ScrollViewer>
      <frame x:Name="ContentFrame" Padding="12,0,12,24" IsTabStop="True" NavigationFailed="ContentFrame_NavigationFailed" />
    </ScrollViewer>
  </NavigationView>

  <frame x:Name="frame" Margin="20,0,0,0" Navigating="OnNavigatingToPage">
    <Frame.ContentTransitions>
      <TransitionCollection>
        <NavigationThemeTransition>
          <NavigationThemeTransition.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo>
            <EntranceNavigationTransitionInfo />
          </NavigationThemeTransition.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo>
        </NavigationThemeTransition>
      </TransitionCollection>
    </Frame.ContentTransitions>
  </frame>

  <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup>
      <VisualState>
        <VisualState.StateTriggers>
          <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="{x:Bind NavView.CompactModeThresholdWidth}" />
        </VisualState.StateTriggers>
        <VisualState.Setters>
          <!-- Leave the next line for left-only navigation. -->
          <Setter Target="ContentFrame.Padding" Value="24,0,24,24" />
        </VisualState.Setters>
      </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
  </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</Grid>
```

Function that opens the selected item in the menu:

```
    private void NavViewItemInvoked(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
    {
        var label = args.InvokedItem as string;
        var pageType =
            label == "Home" ? typeof(HomePage) :
            label == "Add" ? typeof(AddPage) : null;
        if (pageType != null && pageType != AppFrame.CurrentSourcePageType)
        {
            AppFrame.Navigate(pageType);
        }
    }
```

I hope someone could tell me what it's happening or where is the mistake.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you please tell us why you are using 2 frames in your page ? (ContentFrame and AppFrame) . Also, you have a frame with name "frame" I am guessing AppFrame and "frame" are referring to the same instance, is that right ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I'm not very experienced with uwp apps development. I understand that I should have only one frame then. Yes, that "AppFrame" refers to one of those frames, probably that is the mistake, having two frames. I'll try to change it later and I'll give you some feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understood , your requirement is to have a navigation view which will use a frame to navigate between the different pages of the application.

I have simplified your solution a bit hopefully this should help.
In the following solution I have used a single frame for the navigation.

**XAML**

```
<Grid>
    <NavigationView x:Name="NavView" ItemInvoked="NavViewItemInvoked">
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem x:Name="HomePage" Content="Home" Icon="Home" />
            <NavigationViewItem x:Name="AddPage" Content="Add" Icon="Add" />
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>

        <NavigationView.AutoSuggestBox>
            <AutoSuggestBox x:Name="SearchBox" QueryIcon="Find" />
        </NavigationView.AutoSuggestBox>
        <!-- Removed scroll viewer not sure if this is required -->
        <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" IsTabStop="True"
         NavigationFailed="ContentFrame_NavigationFailed" />            
    </NavigationView>
</Grid>
```

**C#**

```
private void NavViewItemInvoked(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
    {
        var label = args.InvokedItem as string;
        var pageType =
            label == "Home" ? typeof(HomePage) :
            label == "Add" ? typeof(AddPage) : null;
        if (pageType != null && pageType != ContentFrame.CurrentSourcePageType)
        {
            ContentFrame.Navigate(pageType);
        }
    }
```

---

[image]

---

Explanation :

As mentioned above, this solution has only one frame for the navigation. 
Whenever user selects an item in the Navigation View, it will navigate the `ContentFrame` to the desired page [`ContentFrame.Navigate(pageType)`];
.

Let me know if you require any more explanation or refer to [Martin Zikmund's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55315425/7325217)

Comment: I think I have it clear now, I really had a mess in that code. Thanks for the answer, is really helpfull

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

The structure of your UI looks like this

- `NavigationView`

  - `Frame` (`ContentFrame`)
- `Frame` (`AppFrame`)

The basic rule in XAML is that for content at the same level, what comes later in the code, is drawn above what comes before. Of course this is very simplified, as you can layout children of a panel in such way they don't overlap, but we are considering your particular case now.

The `NavigationView` and the second `Frame` are on the same level, and are both inside the root `Grid`, without any `Grid.Column` or `Grid.Row` attributes specified. In such case, the `Frame` is directly above the `NavigationView`. At first this does not matter much, as there is no content there and hence the `Frame` is "invisible". Once you actually navigate within the `Frame` however, the page will completely cover the `NavigationView` and that will in turn "disappear".

What I found confusing however, is that you have two `Frame` controls in your code. The one you should actually use is the one named as `ContentFrame`. This one is embedded in the `NavigationView` and that is the most common way to present pages. So if you remove the second `Frame` altogether and change all code to use `ContentFrame` instead, you should get the behavior you want.

Comment: Sorry for answering so late. Ok, Thanks a lot, I'll try to change this as son as possible to use only the  'ContentFrame'. I understand that I don't need to create the same menu in the page that I want to launch, then every page I start from this main page with NavigationView will be embedded in 'ContentFrame', is it that right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right - the Frame acts as the container for pages and manages the navigation stack