# How to allow a C# UWP app manage another UWP app?

Tags: c#, installation, uwp, updates, uninstallation

I want to do some things, which I feel are very simple, but I cannot do. I have looked at numerous websites and StackOverflow questions. One [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33399614/uwp-installer-without-powershell) has helped me a bit by pointing me in the right direction, but I feel I need more than just that.

Here is what I want to do (basically):

- I would like to make a `UWP` app that can be managed by another app.

  - By "managed" I mean:

    - Should be able to install the app.
    - Should be able to uninstall the app.
    - Should be able to check for updates and update the app.
    - It should also be able to launch the app.
  - Optional requirements:

    - While launching the app, I would like to have it set the page of a panel to a certain page. Also fine with it clicking on the navbar and change the panel's page

      - This would be an example of my app would be like (the one with the panel/nav): [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55306225/when-opening-a-new-page-it-overlapses-the-navigationview-menu)
- I would also like an installer (something like a `.exe` file or `.msi` file) for the installing app. Not the `.appinstaller` that visual studio 19 produces. Something like Inno Setup produces.

---

Is any of this possible?

If so, please give me some sample code/instructions/links. I would be very thankful for any advice/points in the right direction as well!

If not, please suggest what other language/framework I should use to accomplish these tasks (Is "tasks" the right word?). I don't mind learning anything and have unlimited time. Don't care about the learning curve either. (If I need C++, I will do it. ONLY IF I NEED IT!!!)

Thanks all!

P.S. I know about WPF or WinForms. I don't want to use them because of their age.

Answer (score 0):

As the Rob Caplan said, PackManager class doesn’t support uwp app, it is suitable for desktop app. So maybe you need to create a wpf app and use [Desktop bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net) to package it into uwp app so that you could use this api. In addition, you could find the sample [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/PackageManagerAddPackage) about installing appx package, its parent directory [Windows-classic-samples/Samples/](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples) also contains other samples you need, such as PackageManagerRemovePackage, etc, please check it.